# Regex to extract just first IP from different pattern events

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to extract just the first IP from below events through regex -

```
For: ${nd:app://${namingDetails}.for.net.sh}, 4.5.3.2, 23.200.06.110 V-
For: 10.10.21.17, 5.18.11.74, 23.36.3.22 V-
For: 23.3.39.1, 21.61.39.21 V-
For: 3.3.39.1 V-
```

So if we consider above events, my regex should match below IP's as first_ip

```
4.5.3.2
10.10.21.17
23.3.39.1
3.3.39.1
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

this is how far i could get -> https://regex101.com/r/6K3AKX/1

```
(?:For:\s)?(?:For:.+)?((?<first_ip>\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))\,
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
^For:\s.*?\b(?<first_ip>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})
```

and grab named capture group `first_ip`.

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `For:\S`: Match `For` followed by a whitespace
- `.*?\b`: Match 0 or more of any characters followed by a word boundary
- `(?<first_ip>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})`: Match IP address in named capture group `first_ip`

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6K3AKX/3)

If you're using php/PCRE then use:

```bash
^For:\s.*?\K\b\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. This looks perfect and works fine but just wanted to know would it be possible to ignore matching loop back ip(127.0.0.1) as i see its popping in some events like -> https://regex101.com/r/WvJ9Yn/1

Comment: Yes it is possible. We can use: `^For:\s.*?\b(?!127\.0\.0\.)(?<first_ip>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})`